# When does the Xur (Agent of the Nine) appear?

Tags: destiny

I recently discovered this fellow in my Grimoire

[image: Agent of the Nine]

Has he made an appearance in the game yet? I haven't come across this individual yet, so is his appearance triggered by story events?

The [wiki](http://www.destinypedia.com/X%C3%BBr,_Agent_of_the_Nine) says

> Xûr sells extremely rare goods in exchange for Strange Coins and only appears on weekends. Xûr's coming and going depends on the planetary alignments.

This seems inconsistent, does he appear every weekend or just when he (Bungie) feel like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Xur](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/X%C3%BBr) appears at 7am EST on Fridays and leaves 7am EST on Sundays. His location has changed each week, but he's usually easy to find if you wander around the Tower for a few minutes.

He sells 1 piece of exotic armor for each class, 1 exotic weapon, and an exotic engram that is guaranteed an exotic (for a random class).

He also sells various upgrades for your sparrow and exp boosters for your weapons.

The main currency he accepts is strange coins, but you can buy the exotic engram with Motes of Light.

Comment: So that's what the Strange Coin is for!

Comment: I think this question was working off limited data. I certainly didn't see Xur around anywhere this weekend. Was I just looking in the wrong place or is he not always around (my thought was that while the Queen's Wrath event is on he might be taking the chance to take a holiday)...

Comment: this past weekend he was hiding in the corner at the bar in the docking bay.

Answer (score 1):

He appears on the weekends in random places in the Tower. You can use the map on the companion app to see exactly where.